# Converting an "If Else" statement to a JSON file

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am having this as an `input`, let's call it `tree`

```
if ( device_type_id <= 1 )
    39 Clicks - 0.61%
    2135 Conversions - 33.32% 
else ( device_type_id > 1 )
    if ( country_id <= 216 )
        1097 Clicks - 17.12%
    else ( country_id > 216 )
        if ( browser_id <= 2 )
            296 Clicks - 4.62%
        else ( browser_id > 2 )
            if ( browser_id <= 4 )
                if ( browser_id <= 3 )
                    if ( operating_system_id <= 2 )
                        262 Clicks - 4.09%
                        1094 Impressions - 17.08%
                    else ( operating_system_id > 2 )
                        if ( operating_system_id <= 4 )
                            281 Clicks - 4.39%
                            220 Impressions - 3.43%
                        else ( operating_system_id > 4 )
                            if ( operating_system_id <= 6 )
                                4 Clicks - 0.06%
                                20 Impressions - 0.31%
                            else ( operating_system_id > 6 )
                                70 Impressions - 1.09%



                else ( browser_id > 3 )
                    if ( operating_system_id <= 2 )
                        19 Clicks - 0.3%
                        21 Impressions - 0.33%
                    else ( operating_system_id > 2 )
                        19 Clicks - 0.3%
                        707 Impressions - 11.03%


            else ( browser_id > 4 )
                113 Clicks - 1.76%
```

Then I created this function using `tree` as an `input` :

```
def function_one(tree):
    network = []
    for line in tree.splitlines() : 
        if line.strip():
            line = line.strip()
            network.append(line)
        else : break
        if not line : break

    res = []
    res.append({'name':'Prediction Result', 'children':parser(network[1:])})
    with open('static/json/structure_sklearn.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(res, outfile)
    return tree
```

As you may see, I used a `parser` function which is :

```
def parser(lines):
    block = []
    while lines :

        if lines[0].startswith('if'):
            bl = ' '.join(lines.pop(0).split()[1:]).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            block.append({'name':bl, 'children':parser(lines)})

            if lines[0].startswith('else'):
                be = ' '.join(lines.pop(0).split()[1:]).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
                block.append({'name':be, 'children':parser(lines)})
        elif not lines[0].startswith(('if','else')):
            block2 = lines.pop(0)
            block.append({'name':block2})
        else:
            break   
    return block
```

My issue is , I don't know in which phase I have missed something because the `json` file created from `function_one` is just :

```
[
   {
      "children":[
         {
            "name":"39 Clicks - 0.61%"
         },
         {
            "name":"2135 Conversions - 33.32%"
         }
      ],
      "name":"Prediction Result"
   }
]
```

Comment: You need to unindent the block starting with `if lines[0].startswith("else")`. Right now, it is part of the code if the line starts with "if", which means it will never get called. This might also want to be an `elif` rather than `if`, but should work either way. Also, you are only popping the first line if it is not an `if` or `else`. Why do this destructive iteration over lines? Just do `for line in lines:`.

Comment: I am having a nested "if" statements because I want to create a nested structure in the json file, for that reason I used "while" and "destructive iteration" so I can access to next line inside "if" statement and test the next one with "else", if I use "for", I will have separated statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the modification I suggested:

```
def parser(lines):
    block = []
    while lines :

        if lines[0].startswith('if'):
            bl = ' '.join(lines.pop(0).split()[1:]).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            block.append({'name':bl, 'children':parser(lines)})

        elif lines[0].startswith('else'):
            be = ' '.join(lines.pop(0).split()[1:]).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            block.append({'name':be, 'children':parser(lines)})

        elif not lines[0].startswith(('if','else')):
            block2 = lines.pop(0)
            block.append({'name':block2})
        else:
            break   
    return block
```

With this change, I get the following JSON indented output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Prediction Result", 
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "39 Clicks - 0.61%"
      }, 
      {
        "name": "2135 Conversions - 33.32%"
      }, 
      {
        "name": " device_type_id > 1 ", 
        "children": [
          {
            "name": " country_id <= 216 ", 
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "1097 Clicks - 17.12%"
              }, 
              {
                "name": " country_id > 216 ", 
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": " browser_id <= 2 ", 
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "name": "296 Clicks - 4.62%"
                      }, 
                      {
                        "name": " browser_id > 2 ", 
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "name": " browser_id <= 4 ", 
                            "children": [
                              {
                                "name": " browser_id <= 3 ", 
                                "children": [
                                  {
                                    "name": " operating_system_id <= 2 ", 
                                    "children": [
                                      {
                                        "name": "262 Clicks - 4.09%"
                                      }, 
                                      {
                                        "name": "1094 Impressions - 17.08%"
                                      }, 
                                      {
                                        "name": " operating_system_id > 2 ", 
                                        "children": [
                                          {
                                            "name": " operating_system_id <= 4 ", 
                                            "children": [
                                              {
                                                "name": "281 Clicks - 4.39%"
                                              }, 
                                              {
                                                "name": "220 Impressions - 3.43%"
                                              }, 
                                              {
                                                "name": " operating_system_id > 4 ", 
                                                "children": [
                                                  {
                                                    "name": " operating_system_id <= 6 ", 
                                                    "children": [
                                                      {
                                                        "name": "4 Clicks - 0.06%"
                                                      }, 
                                                      {
                                                        "name": "20 Impressions - 0.31%"
                                                      }, 
                                                      {
                                                        "name": " operating_system_id > 6 ", 
                                                        "children": [
                                                          {
                                                            "name": "70 Impressions - 1.09%"
                                                          }
                                                        ]
                                                      }
                                                    ]
                                                  }
                                                ]
                                              }
                                            ]
                                          }
                                        ]
                                      }
                                    ]
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I can't tell if this is the actual form or output you are looking for, but it does appear to include all the nodes from the original tree source.

EDIT:

Here is a cleaner (and likely faster) way to walk your list of lines, using an iterator.

```
def parser(lines):
    lines_iter = iter(lines)
    block = []
    for line in lines_iter:

        if line.startswith('if'):
            bl = ' '.join(line.split()[1:]).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            block.append({'name':bl, 'children':parser(lines_iter)})

        elif line.startswith('else'):
            be = ' '.join(line.split()[1:]).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
            block.append({'name':be, 'children':parser(lines_iter)})

        elif not line.startswith(('if','else')):
            block2 = line
            block.append({'name':block2})
        else:
            break   
    return block
```

I changed the call in function_one to call `parser(network)` instead of `parser(network[1:])`, but otherwise the rest of the code is unchanged. `list.pop(0)` is slow, especially for large lists, because the underlying array has to shift every element down by one.

Comment: That's exactly the output I am looking for !